# Jssor slider editor code availability

Tags: jssor

Where can I find code for JSSOR slider maker/editor found at http://jssor.com/demos/new.slider/=edit

Is this code open source?

Answer (score 2):

JSSOR is not open source - if you want to build slideshow for your website I suggest you Slider Maker (I'm the author).

It's a [jQuery Slideshow Maker](https://www.slider-maker.com/) with admin panel.

You can make slideshows without coding anything, there's nothing to install and no database. Slider Maker is ready to use on any PHP sever.

Main features :

- Very simple to use
- Animated text layers
- Titles, captions, links
- Multilanguage (UI & slideshows text content)
- Live preview
- Sizing & other options available
- Ken Burns effect
- 3 lines of code to copy/paste to publish your slideshow
- Awesome customer support

Admin panel Demo available at https://www.slider-maker.com/slidermaker/admin/login.php

Photo slideshow templates here : https://www.slider-maker.com/slidermaker/demo-files/